# C++ Use Child Member's Variable in Parent Class Member Function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have something along the lines of

```
class A {
 public:
    class subA {
     public:
        // some variables
    };
    std::vector<subA> children;
    void foo() {
        // modify children
    }
};

class B : public A {
 public:
    class subB : public A::subA {
     public:
        // some extra variables
    }
    std::vector<subB> children;
}

B b;
b.foo();
```

foo() only uses base attributes of subA. Is there anyway I can have B.foo() use the children composed of subB instead of the children of subA?

Since A is not aware of subB, does this mean I have to make foo virtual and rewrite the same code so it uses the correct children vector (composed of subB)? Any better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to have two member variables with the same name?

Comment: Make `foo()` virtual and have `B::foo` work on `B::children` while `A::foo` works on `A::children`. Does an object of type `B` use `A::children` at all though? If not, then you might need to rethink your method of inheritance or ask if inheritance at all is correct in this case.

Comment: @Brian I want class B to use the vector of subB whenever children is used in the code of A. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to do this? There is nothing in A that uses any of the extra variables of subB so I thought it should be compatible?

Comment: You could make `children` be of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<subA>>`, then you only have one vector and it can handle anything that has `subA` as a base class.

Comment: You also might consider a template class instead of inheritance.

Comment: @JohnFilleau B does not use A::children and only uses B::children. Since subB is a superset of subA, I don't want to have to rewrite foo() to do the exact same thing in B (copy-paste function).Is there some way I can tell foo() to use whatever instance's children it is called from?

Comment: @JohnFilleau let me try the ```std::vector<std::unique_ptr<subA>>```

A little confused though as wouldn't b.foo() still call A::foo() which isn't aware of anything inside of B? I still need some of the functionality of subB in B. Would I just force cast it to subB at that point knowing that is true?

Comment: Of course only use `std::unique_ptr` if `A` should own all of those `subA`'s. If not, a vector of naked pointers is fine.

Comment: You said that `A::foo` is only doing operations on `children` that are compatible with `subA`'s signature. If that's the case then it doesn't need to know anything about `subB` or `B`. If you need a `B::foo` that knows about the structure of `subB`, then yeah there's no way around that besides either a virtual `A::foo`/`B::foo` thingy (that's the technical term ;D ) or having `subA` have a virtual method that `subB` overwrites.